# CMake: Libicu not found

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-16.04, icu

While compiling my project with CMake I get:

```
<myPproject(file.c.o)>: In function `icuLikeCompare':
<myPproject(file.c.o)>: undefined reference to `u_foldCase_55'
<myPproject(file.c.o)>: undefined reference to `u_foldCase_55'
<myPproject(file.c.o)>: In function `icuCollationColl':
<myPproject(file.c.o): undefined reference to `ucol_strcoll_55'
...
```

I am building with Qt and apparently I am using my Ubuntu distribution headers of libicu and trying to link to the ICU that's bundled with QT. I see the project is linkint to:

```
/home/me/Qt/5.9/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so /home/me/Qt/5.9/5.9.1/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: in your cmake, did you link your libraries to your project using link_target_libraries(project ${PATH_TO_QT_LIBRARIES}) ?

Comment: Yes, they are linked like that